# Meaning of ~ようかな between "I wonder if I should...." and "I guess I'll...."

Tags: nuances

As fair as I'm aware and have read in grammar dictionaries, ~ようかな can take both meanings of "I wonder if I should...." and "I guess I'll....". Obviously, there is a big difference between the two as the former is simply pondering a possibility and the latter is making a direct volitional statement with a bit of uncertainty. I wouldn't want to convey the wrong message.

How are these distinguished?

Comment: Related?: [きっと and かな used in a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76694/%e3%81%8d%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a8-and-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa-used-in-a-sentence/76696#76696)

Comment: Thanks! Some great information but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Your question: "How are these distinguished?". The linked answer: "...depending on the context and the intonation". For people to help further you'll have to be a bit more specific with your question. Why doesn't the link answer your question? What information are you still missing?