# What does かな mean here?

Tags: grammar

From Seishun Cinderella ch. 1,

> 彼氏はいないけど別にいらない**かな**って思っている、恋愛は私には向いてないし

I don't understand the purpose of かな here. This form of ないかな doesn't seem to express desire or hope in this context.「別にいらない」indicates that the speaker doesn't want a boyfriend. Adding かな after it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Does this help, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19809/9831

Comment: `向けてないし` -> should be 向**い**てないし, no?

Comment: @Chocolate 1. Yes that helped. Does it express doubt? 2. Yes you are right.

Comment: Yes the かな here should just be the question particle mentioned in the post above. @JohnDavies

Comment: かな just leaves a small possibility that she may have a BF by chance.  If she explicitly said 'I don't need a boyfriend,' she would be lying if she later got into a relationship.  It's possible that she's actually desperately looking for a boyfriend, but no one is interested in her, so she covers it up by saying 'I don't need a boyfriend. Romantic relationships aren't for me.' while leaving a possibility.  Either way it works like insurance. lol.

Answer (score 2):

"かな" here means "probably / maybe"

She's not sure if she need a boyfriend or not.